# Subfigure caption on side of the first figure

Tags: positioning, subcaption

I have a 110 images which I have arranged using subfigures in the form of 10*11.

In each row, I want to put the caption for every first image like (A) (B) and so on. I have used \usepackage{caption,subcaption} but it didn't work out. It gives the following error:

`! Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation(subcaption) with the subfigure package.`

The code is as follows:

`

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} % define this before the line numbering.
\usepackage{ruler}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens,labelsep=space,font=small}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage[width=122mm,left=12mm,paperwidth=146mm,height=193mm,top=12mm,paperheight=217mm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\cfbox}[2]{%
    \colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
    {\color{#1}%
    \fboxsep=0.1mm%padding thickness
    \fboxrule=1pt%border thickness
    \fbox{\color{currentcolor}#2}}%
}
\begin{figure*}[!t]
\centering
\subfigure{
\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{figures/New_Figures/Figure_2-eps/main1.jpg}
\hspace{0.2cm}\cfbox{green}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{figures/New_Figures/Figure_2-eps/1.jpg}}
\hspace{-0.2cm}\cfbox{green}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{figures/New_Figures/Figure_2-eps/2.jpg}}
\hspace{-0.2cm}\cfbox{green}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{figures/New_Figures/Figure_2-eps/3.jpg}}
\hspace{-0.2cm}\cfbox{green}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{figures/New_Figures/Figure_2-eps/4.jpg}}
\hspace{-0.2cm}\cfbox{green}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{figures/New_Figures/Figure_2-eps/5.jpg}}
\hspace{-0.2cm}\cfbox{green}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{figures/New_Figures/Figure_2-eps/6.jpg}}
\hspace{-0.2cm}\cfbox{green}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{figures/New_Figures/Figure_2-eps/7.jpg}}
\hspace{-0.2cm}\cfbox{green}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{figures/New_Figures/Figure_2-eps/8.jpg}}
\hspace{-0.2cm}\cfbox{green}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{figures/New_Figures/Figure_2-eps/9.jpg}}
\hspace{-0.2cm}\cfbox{green}{\includegraphics[height=1cm,width=1cm]{figures/New_Figures/Figure_2-eps/10.jpg}}}
```

`

Is there any other method to do such thing ?

More specifically I am trying to achieve what's there in Fig 5 of [this](https://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/publications/2015/Crowley15/crowley15.pdf) paper.

[image: many faces]

Comment: Seems you are loading obsolete package `subfigure` somewhere. You cannot use the up-to-date package `subcaption` in conjunction with the deprecated package `subfigure`. I would recommend to remove `subfigure` and change the usages of `subfigure` into corresponding usage of `subcaption`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Please note, we almost always need a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) to reproduce and understand a problem and to test our own suggestions. Most questions without MWE are closed as unclear.

Comment: Sorry for not providing the MWE. Here's the snippet of the latex code. Actually in the first figure of the subfigure, I want to insert a letter like (a) to represent the whole row. I checked again the compatibility of the packages but don't know how it works. I will be glad if you could suggest some other alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of tweaking packages it is not too difficult to write your own environment. First, I suggest to define a separate command for loading an image that takes care of sizing, formatting, and positioning the image.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\img[1]%
  {\raisebox
    {\dimexpr-0.5\height+0.5ex}%
    {\includegraphics[width=10mm]{#1}}%
  }
```

To obtain labeled image rows in a figure, use

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{imgrows}[...]% optional width, default is \textwidth
    \imgrow \label{...}% label for later reference
      \img{...} \img{...}\img{...}
    \imgrow \label{...}% label for later reference
      \img{...} \img{...}\img{...}
  \end{imgrows}
  \caption{...}% Caption of figure
\end{figure}
```

This requires the following definitions in the preamble:

```
% Defines an environment for labeled image rows
% \begin{imgrows}
%   \imgrow\label{...} images ...
%   \imgrow\label{...} images ...
% \end{imgrows}
% To be used inside a figure
\newcounter{row}
\renewcommand\therow{\thefigure\alph{row}}
\newenvironment{imgrows}[1][\textwidth]%
  {\begin{minipage}{#1}%
   \setcounter{row}{0}%
   \stepcounter{figure}%
  }%
  {\addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
   \end{minipage}%
  }
\newcommand\imgrow
  {\par\noindent
   \refstepcounter{row}%
   \makebox[1.5em][r]{(\alph{row})}\
  }
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand\img[1]%
  {\raisebox
    {\dimexpr-0.5\height+0.5ex}%
    {\includegraphics[width=10mm]{#1}}%
  }

% Defines an environment for labeled image rows
% \begin{imgrows}
%   \imgrow\label{...} images ...
%   \imgrow\label{...} images ...
% \end{imgrows}
% To be used inside a figure
\newcounter{row}
\renewcommand\therow{\thefigure\alph{row}}
\newenvironment{imgrows}[1][\textwidth]%
  {\begin{minipage}{#1}%
   \setcounter{row}{0}%
   \stepcounter{figure}%
  }%
  {\addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
   \end{minipage}%
  }
\newcommand\imgrow
  {\par\noindent
   \refstepcounter{row}%
   \makebox[1.5em][r]{(\alph{row})}\
  }
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{imgrows}%
\imgrow\label{imgs:first}
  \img{example-image}
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%

\imgrow\label{imgs:second}
  \img{example-image}
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%

\imgrow\label{imgs:third}
  \img{example-image}
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
\end{imgrows}
\caption{Too many images}
\end{figure}

See rows \ref{imgs:first}, \ref{imgs:second}, and \ref{imgs:third},
but also \ref{imgs:fourth} and \ref{imgs:fifth}.
\begin{figure}
\begin{imgrows}%
\imgrow\label{imgs:fourth}
  \img{example-image}
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%

\imgrow\label{imgs:fifth}
  \img{example-image}
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
  \img{example-image-a}%
  \img{example-image-b}%
\end{imgrows}
\caption{Even more images}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```